# Distinct count using countifs in excel

Tags: excel

I have a following excel data format:

```
ID       Category      Type
P-1      A1            Pro
P-2      A2            Demo
P-3      A2            
P-4      A1            Pro
P-4      A1            Pro
P-5      B1            Pro
P-6      B3            Demo
```

Using the above excel I need to create the following format and get count.

```
Category    Pro    Demo    Blank
A1          2      1       0
A2          0      0       1
B1          1      0       0
B3          0      1       0
```

I'm using `=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIFS())` but it is not working as expected.

Comment: What is you excel version?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: You haven't clarified your Excel version.

Comment: @JosWoolley - I'm using Microsoft 365

Comment: You could use a data model pivot table with distinct count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula I used-

```
E2 =UNIQUE(B2:B8)
F2 =SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$A$8,($B$2:$B$8=$E2)*($C$2:$C$8=F$1),""))<>""))
G2 =SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$A$8,($B$2:$B$8=$E2)*($C$2:$C$8=G$1),""))<>""))
H2 =SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$A$8,($B$2:$B$8=$E2)*($C$2:$C$8=""),""))<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `#` for automatic spill the results. `=--(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$8,$E2#,$C$2:$C$8,F$1)>0)`

Comment: I want to count distinct `ID` based on the given category and type. I'm getting value only 1 or 0 in my large data set.

Comment: @SophiaWilson See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use countifs

```
E2    =UNIQUE(B2:B8)
F2    =COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$8,$E2,$C$2:$C$8,F$1)  
G2    =COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$8,$E2,$C$2:$C$8,G$1)
H2    =SUM(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8,$E2)-$F2-$G2)


A        B             C        D      E             F        G         H
ID       Category      Type            Category      Pro      Demo      Blank
P-1      A1            Pro             A1            3        0         0
P-2      A2            Demo            A2            0        1         1
P-3      A2                            A3            1        0         0
P-4      A1            Pro             A4            0        1         0     
P-4      A1            Pro
P-5      B1            Pro
P-6      B3            Demo
```